# multiple terminals to simulate multiple clients

Tags: python, bash

I created 2 python scripts which simulate a server and a client for a file transferring server. I start the server in a terminal, then start the client in another terminal. Everything connects just fine, on the client side the user gets asked to choose the number of the file to download, he types in the number in his terminal then the file gets downloaded. Everything fine here. It also supports multiple clients: I've tried opening 2 client terminals, both can connect to the server, each types in a number and they download their files concurrently(file transfers are different threads on the server side). Now what I need to do is to check the impact of concurrent clients (2,4,10) on the download speed. This means I need to write a script that simulates several concurrent clients, and the input (number of the file to download) for each of them. i have no idea how to do that. Could you help me out on a way to do that please?

Note: this can be done in Python, Bash or anything else. I realize this is just a big paragraph, sorry for that. Feel free to tell me if you require any other info to help me out.

Also, I've seen people mention expect, but they also said it was a bad idea to mix it with bash.

Finally, I am aware this is most likely a common issue/question, but despite trying several google searches, no luck here. So feel free to indicate me what to search for on google or any stackoverflow previous question.
I thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you add the commands you are using to connect a single client so that we can incorporate them into the script?

Comment: Have you looked into using a queue to process the calls and then using `Popen` to run multiple of them. Then you can time what the response times are of different numbers of calls.

Comment: I'm basically just typing python3 client.py in my terminal. in the client.py I used a socket.connect((HOST,PORT)) . dont know if that answers your question @Socowi

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim thank you for that input I'll look into that. I'm not familiar with this so thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you simulate a single client by first running `python3 client.py` in your terminal and then entering a number for the download.

You can automate entering the number using a *here string*: `python3 client.py <<< 5`.

Now, run this *n* times in parallel to simulate *n* clients:

```
#! /bin/bash
for i in {1..100}; do
  python3 client.py <<< 5 &
done
```

Here we choose *n*=100 and the fixed input `5`. Of course you can randomize that. To pick a random number between 1 and 9 replace the `5` by `$(( RANDOM % 9 + 1 ))`.

Comment: I dont know much about Bash, but this answer was as clear as it gets. Thank you very much, it perfectly answers my need!

Comment: sry to bother again but I have a follow-up question. To better understand this <<<, I've tried adding a confirmation input: like previously the client is asked the number of the file (5 in your code), but then he is asked to type y to confirm. Yet I cannot simply add <<< y after <<<5 in the code example you provided as the order of commands is messed up ( one client.py reads a "y" as the number of file input). any idea on how I could do that?

Comment: You have to write everything in one string, one line per input. Use `python ... <<< $'5\ny'` (the `$''` is need so that `\n` is interpreted as a linebreak) or `printf %s\\n 5 y | python ...`.  Glad I could help by the way :)